# Preventing Snapd installation with a negative pin-priority no longer works

Tags: package-management, firefox, snap, 22.04

I've previously uninstalled `snapd` and installed a non-snap Firefox from `ppa:mozillateam/ppa`. I'm trying to keep it this way, but my FF was just auto-updated to a snap version, and snapd was auto-installed again. How can I prevent it?

I have a file with following contents to prevent `snapd` installation, at `/etc/apt/preferences.d/nosnap.pref`:

```
Package: snapd
Pin: release a=*
Pin-Priority: -10
```

I also have `/etc/apt/preferences.d/mozillateam.pref` with following contents:

```
Package: firefox*
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-mozillateam
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

This doesn't seem to work anymore. My non-snap firefox was just auto-updated to a snap version, with `snapd` being installed automatically.

Interestingly, `sudo apt autoremove snap` rolled the firefox back to a non-snap version, and `sudo apt update` says there's nothing to update.

On the other hand, `sudo apt install snapd --dry-run` no longer seems to be blocked by by the above config files.

Not sure if it matters, but `apt-cache policy -q | grep snap` prints following, among other things:

```
snapd -> 2.55.5+22.04 с приоритетом 1
snapd -> 2.55.3+22.04 с приоритетом -10
```

---

As requested, the output of `apt-cache policy snapd`:

```
apt-cache policy snapd
snapd:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.55.5+22.04
  Version table:
     2.55.5+22.04 1 (phased 70%)
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
     2.55.3+22.04 -10
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Interestingly, I tried it on a different machine (which didn't receive this auto-update), and there `2.55.5+22.04` had pin priority `-10`, not `1`, and was marked as `(phased 80%)`.

Comment: wfhere comes this from `snapd -> 2.55.5+22.04 с приоритетом 1` the lower version is blocked with negative pinning but this version not.

Comment: @nobody I'd also like to know where it comes from. I didn't modify any other configs, and grepping for "snap" in `/etc/apt` didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: Please check it with `apt-cache policy snapd` this will show sources too.

Comment: @nobody Added output.

Comment: what ubuntu version?

Comment: @ThomasWard 22.04, as tagged. Xubuntu, if it matters.

Comment: Never seen this (phased) part. You can also use `n=jammy*` in your nosnap.pref but this is only working in  jammy.

Comment: @nobody Thanks, it seems to work (i.e. `sudo apt install snapd` fails). Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a clean solution; more a workaround.

```
n=jammy*
```

-n means codename (here jammy)

The rule for those expressions is that they can occur anywhere where a string (here jammy)can occur
Means does not matter if snapd is offerd in jammy or jammy-updates or jammy-security. Please take also a look in [man apt_preferences](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man5/apt_preferences.5.html) There I found it.